# Can anyone with the shared google link add files to that folder, without having a google account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a google drive shared folder link, which has the write privileges such as add files or edit them.

My question is can anyone without google account can still add files if he/she has this link.
Because I tried myself and It does not allow, but at the same time why does the privilege say that anyone with this link can add files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Trying to upload to a public folder will require you to sign-in to your Google account. The interface looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question/quandary.  Note that Google's support page says that if the folder is shared with "edit" permissions, the non-Google account should be able to add/edit/delete files to the folder.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529

I have submitted a Google Drive Support Inquiry 9-6348000021871 on this topic. It also points to this thread.  Hopefully the fix will be implemented soon.